# React Native - Native Base - Showing error

Tags: react-native

This is the Package.Json File
Following are package versions I am using

```html
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "native-base": "2.8.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^6.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

This is My HearderPart.Js Component Code

I am unable to use native-base package in my component.

```js
import {Container, Header, Content, Footer, Title} from 'native-base';
import React, {Component} from 'react-native';

export default class HeaderPart extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Title>Header</Title>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <Title>Content</Title> 
                </Content>
                <Footer>
                    <Title>Footer</Title>
                </Footer>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Error Message

[image]

Comment: Try shutting the bundler down and then restarting it with `expo start -c`

Comment: still the same error, I guess native-base is not compatible with my react version.. is it so?

Comment: its expo..........

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are importing `React` from the wrong place. Currently in your `HeaderPart` component you are doing the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react-native';
```

You should be importing `React` like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Importing `React` correctly should fix your issue.